# Getting a null while trying to load a prefab from resources folder

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have an prefab loaded in Resources folder , but when i trying to get it from code it returning me NULL. How can i do it right? I just want to get prefab and get access to my UI components located in prefab , then change UI values from prefab Object..

[image]

```
GameObject alertPrefab = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/AlertPrefab"));
```

Comment: Can you first add a public variable `public GameObject alertPrefab;` and then manually drag the prefab onto the field in the UI? Check if that works without any errors. Also make sure that your `AlertPrefab` has an extension `.prefab`

Comment: Think you should do as Meehow's commnet to workaround and isolate if your NullPointer is not a problem with your prefab because your instantiation seems right. Or try ("Assets/Prefabs/AlertPrefab") or just ("/Prefabs/AlertPrefab") but I'm not sure if it makes any difference indeed =p

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an `public` or `[SerializeField]` variable of type `GameObject` and drag the `Prefab` you want to use, to the `script` inside the `Inspector`.

**Create public var**

[image]

**Drag the prefab from prefab folder to the script**

[image]

**And than instantiate it from the public var inside the script**

```
private void spawnNewFood () {
    float rand = Random.Range (2, 6);
    int factor = ((int)rand % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
    float x = rand * factor;
    float z = rand * factor;

    Vector3 positionFood = new Vector3 (x, 0, z);
    Instantiate (_food, positionFood, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

All asset names & paths in Unity use forward slashes, paths using backslashes will not work.

"Prefabs/AlertPrefab") you cant do like that

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        go.renderer.material.mainTexture = Resources.Load("glass", typeof(Texture2D));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a forward slash: `/` and this is a backslash: `\ `. Why would `"Prefabs/AlertPrefab"` be wrong? I confirm

Comment: Regrettably, GabLeRoux is correct -- this answer is totally wrong. The path *is* using forward slashes.